# driver.get() takes too much time - Python Selenium PhantomJs

Tags: python, selenium, flask, phantomjs

I'm using python with selenium-Phantomjs to execute some url. But when it goes to `driver.get(url)` it got stuck over there. When I use chrome instead of it, its working perfectly fine.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium import webdriver
import time

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/53 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87")

def Foo(url):
    try:
        driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap,service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true'])
        # chromedriver = "/Documents/chromedriver"
        # os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
        # driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"Path To Chrome Driver")
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(8)
        status = "successful"
    except (Exception) as e:
        print(e)
        status = "unsuccessful"
        driver.close()
    return status

url ="https://www.zomato.com/clients/reviews_new.php?entity_type=restaurant&entity_id=53892&start_date=2012-01-01&end_date=2017-05-05"
status = Foo(url)
print(status)
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I find the alternative myself. I just used headless chrome instead of phantomjs.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
import time,os

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

def Foo(url):
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(8)
        status = "successful"
    except (Exception) as e:
        print(e)
        status = "unsuccessful"
        #driver.close()
    return status

url ="https://www.zomato.com/clients/reviews_new.php?entity_type=restaurant&entity_id=53892&start_date=2012-01-01&end_date=2017-05-05"
status = Foo(url)
print(status)
```

But first you have to install `xvfb` to run chrome headlessly. You can install it using `sudo apt-get install xvfb`. You also need to install pyvirtualdisplay package. That can be done by `pip3 install pyvirtualdisplay`.